# Python Tkinter - how to get informations in a tk.toplevel class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello i'm having issues about get acces of functions or variables in a tk.Toplevel class because he wants a parent. So how can i get informations from that class?

I've two .py files:

the first is the frame core:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test2(tk.Toplevel): 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #[...]
        self.createwidg()

    def createwidg(self):
        #[...]
        pass
        
    def examplefunction(self):
        #[...]
        return True

class Test1(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #[...]
        self.createwidg()

    def createwidg(self):
        #[...]
        pass
        
    def openwindow(self):
        window=Test2(self)
        window.grab_set()
```

the second one is where I will mainloop the frame and get access of these informations.

So how can I access a function, examplefunction, that's in tk.Toplevel but out the tk.Tk?

Comment: It's not clear what information you're asking about. `Test2` doesn't seem to have any information.

Comment: as i said, i need to get access to a function that's in the second class (examplefunction) but out the tk.Tk

Comment: This is the same question you asked yesterday. 'Python Tkinter - How add a notebook class into a tk.toplevel?' This question is a slightly renamed answer I gave you! `Toplevel` exists to create child widgets which is why it requires a `Tk` parent.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with tkinter. You need to save a reference to `window`, and then you can access it like any other python object.

```
class Test1(tk.Tk):
    ...
    def openwindow(self):
        self.window=Test2(self)
        self.window.grab_set()

    def call_examplefunction(self):
        self.window.examplefunction()
```

If you need to do this outside of the scope of `Test1`, you need to save a reference to the instance of `Test1`:

```
test1 = Test1(...)
...
test1.call_examplefunction()
```

Comment: Man as i said: I need to call this function OUT the tk.Tk not in tk.Tk class

Imagine creating a new file where u loop the main too and u want to access to this tk.toplevel function but out the tk.Tk class (like u written)

Comment: @Diaskyyy: the rule is the same:  you need to keep a reference. If it's outside of `Test1`, then you can keep a reference to `Test1` (eg: `test1=Test1(...); ... test1.call_examplefunction()`)

Comment: No because the function is in tk.Toplevel not in tk.Tk and i can't access to it because he needs the parent master

Comment: The question is: How to access to a tk.Toplevel class (that he needs the parent master and u can't reference it without the root) function?

Comment: @Diaskyyy: you are missing the point. Some code must create an instance of the class. It thus can save a reference to that class and use it, or pass it to other classes that need it. This is not anything unique to tkinter or `Toplevel` widgets. If you need a method from a class, save a reference to the instance of the class and then call the method on the instance. This is fundamental to python programming.